# How to increase the execution timeout in php?

Tags: php

How to increase transaction timeout? I want to upload videos, but large size of videos not uploaded?

It throws error `The process *** exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.`

Comment: Define "transaction timeout". What doesn't work where?

Comment: why do you think its "transaction" timeout?

Comment: short videos uploaded successfully. but long video not uploaded, i think time out.

Comment: ini_set('post_max_size','200M');
 ini_set('upload_max_filesize','200M');
 ini_set('max_execution_time','200M');
 ini_set('max_input_time','200M');
 ini_set('memory_limit','200M');
 set_time_limit(65536);

Comment: me also applied above code but.... nothing done.

Comment: me create .htaccess file and put the following code :

Comment: php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
php_value post_max_size 500M
php_value max_execution_time 500
php_value max_input_time 500

Comment: it is better to split the file before upload it. There are many apps that can be used. I preffer plupload.

Comment: check it out http://codingbin.com/connection-timeout-error-php/

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You need to change some settings in your php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M 
;or whatever size you want

max_execution_time = 60
; also, higher if you must - sets the maximum time in seconds
```

Where your PHP.ini is located depends on your system environment. For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Comment: sorry, I've no clue what you mean by that :(

Comment: @Aamir, You need to have permission from your webhost to change in the configruation of your web server. Often, they wont let you change stuff like that.

Comment: can i change upload_max_filesize  and max_execution_time in htaccess file?

Comment: @hanees, if i'll change in php.ini file i think it will also create problem when we will upload it, bcoz it is on our local system, so i want to change exexution time via php code in that file.

Comment: then you will need to change the php.ini parameters on the fly via set_time_limit() [ http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php ] , but make sure to have safe mode of when using it. You can change any PHP Value via ini_set() http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php - including upload_max_filesize, however if it works may depend on your systems configuration. And yes you can set some values in the .htaccess via php_flag look at http://www.karakas-online.de/EN-Book/change-php-parameters.html

Comment: @Aamir the answer is obvious. Ask your host admin if they ever allow such an upload. This host's admin is onw to whom you should address your question, not stackoverflow.

Comment: @Col , I disagree, he wants to make the changes on the fly and not over the whole application, so he asks how he can do that. And even if he were to ask how he can just change some stuff in the php.ini it may be a newbie question, but an legit question all the same.

Comment: @Hannes ___safe_mode___ [`has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode)

Comment: @IulianOnofrei this comment is 4 Years old

Comment: @Hannes I know, I just commented that for other users that don't notice it or don't know it _(like I did)_, so they don't go on searching what's _safe_mode_. :D

Comment: @IulianOnofrei alright, just feeld the need to point that out :D, but maybe if you don't know what it is its still good to look it up … "Those who cannot learn from history are doomed to repeat it" and all that …

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 73):

You should be able to do during runtime too using

`set_time_limit(100);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

or in your vhost-config

`php_admin_value max_execution_time 10000`

Having a global execution time limit that is LOW is mostly a good idea for performance-reasons on not-so-reliable applications. So you might want to only allow those scripts to run longer that absolutely have to.

p.s.: Dont forget about post_max_size and upload_max_filesize (like the first answer told allready)

Comment: If you set it then sleep will be ignored

Answer (score 25):

To complete the answer of Hannes.

You need to change some setting in your php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M 
;or whatever size you want

max_execution_time = 60
; also, higher if you must
```

If someone want put in unlimited (I don't know why but if you want), you can set the time to 0:

You need to change some setting in your php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 0 

max_execution_time = 0
```

And if you don't know where is your php.ini. You can do a file "name.php" in your server and put:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And on your website, you can see the config of your php.ini and it's marked where is it.

### Edit on 9 January 2015:

If you can't access your php.ini, you have two more options.

You can set this line directly in your "name.php" file but I don't find for upload_max_filesize for this option:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Or in ".htaccess"

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 0
php_value max_execution_time 0
```

Answer (score 17):

if what you need to do is specific only for 1 or 2 pages i suggest to use [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) so it did not affect the whole application.

```
set_time_limit(some_values);
```

but ofcourse these 2 values (post_max_size & upload_max_filesize) are subject to investigate.

you either can set it via [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function

```
ini_set('post_max_size','20M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','2M');
```

or directly in php.ini file like response above by Hannes, or even set it iin .htaccess like below

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to be using **Microsoft IIS** server, in addition to the *php.ini* settings mentioned by others, you may need to increase the execution timeout settings for the PHP FastCGI application in the IIS Server Manager:

Step 1) Open the IIS Server Manager (usually under *Server Manager* in the Start Menu, then *Tools* / *Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager*).

Step 2) Click on the main connection (not specific to any particular domain).

Step 3) Under the *IIS* section, find *FastCGI Settings* (shown below).

[image]

Step 4) Therein, right-click the PHP application and select *Edit...*.

Step 5) Check the timeouts (shown below).

[image]

In my case, the default timeouts here were 70 and 90 seconds; the former of which was causing a *500 Internal Server Error* on PHP scripts that took longer than 70 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

As an addition to above answers, you may use `set_time_limit()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

passing `0` as an argument will make your script run with no time limit.

Comment: set_time_limit() has nothing to do with file uploads

Comment: This is not accurate enough Col. Shrapnel. While on Unix environments the max-execution time is compared to the cumulative CPU-time used by the php-thread, on windows systems the absolute time is used. Uploading is mostly "idle-time" (IO-Wait). But as you see uploads can stop when it takes too long even though.

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot edit php.ini (on your server for example) you can attempt to change the php.ini parameters from within your php code. Try:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 'NUMBER OF SECONDS TO ALLOW BEFORE TIMEOUT');
```

If that doesn't work, try also setting 'set_time_limit' in the same way, beyond that I'd say your only option is to contact your host. These settings cannot be modified while in safe mode.

Comment: Hannes got this a minute before I posted, and correctly points out that set_time_limit() should not be set by ini_set, as stated in this answer but by putting the seconds in the brackets. Voted hannes up.

Answer (score 3):

You had a typo: `ini_set('max_input_time','200M')` - value set needs to be an int, like `ini_set('max_input_time','200')`

Answer (score 3):

First check the `php.ini` file path by `phpinfo()`; and then changed `PHP.INI` params:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
memory_limit = 1500M
post_max_size = 1500M
max_execution_time = 30
```

restarted Apache

```
set_time_limit(0); // safe_mode is off

ini_set('max_execution_time', 500); //500 seconds
```

**Note**: you can also use command to find `php.ini` in Linux

```
locate `php.ini`
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you are specifically asking about the PHP timeout, but what no  one else seems to have mentioned is that there can also be a timeout on the webserver and it can look very similar to the PHP timeout.

So if you have tried:

1. Increasing the timeout in php.ini by adding a line: max_execution_time = {number of seconds i.e. 60 for one minute}
2. Increasing the timeout in your script itself by adding: ini_set('max_execution_time','{number of seconds i.e. 60 for one minute}');

And you have checked with the phpinfo() function that max_execution_time has indeed be increased, then you might want to try adding this to .htaccess which will make sure Apache itself does not time out:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1]
RewriteRule .* - [E=noconntimeout:1]
```

More info here:
https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/php-script-keeps-timing-out-despite-ini-set/

Answer (score 2):

Test if you are is safe mode - if not - set the time limit (Local Value) to what you want:

```
if(!ini_get('safe_mode')){

    echo "safe mode off";
    set_time_limit(180);// seconds

    phpinfo();// see 'max_execution_time'
}
```

*You cannot set time limit this way if safe mode 'on'.

Answer (score 1):

optional : if you set config about php.ini but still can't upload

-this is php function to check error code

```
$error_type = [];
$error_type[0] = "There is no error";
$error_type[1] = "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.";
$error_type[2] = "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.";
$error_type[3] = "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.";
$error_type[4] = "No file was uploaded.";
//$error_type["5"] = "";
$error_type[6] = "Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 5.0.3.";
$error_type[7] = "Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.";
$error_type[8] = "A PHP extension stopped the file upload. PHP does not provide a way to ascertain which extension caused the file upload to stop; examining the list of loaded extensions with phpinfo() may help. Introduced in PHP 5.2.0.";
//------------------------------
//--> show msg error.
$status_code = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["error"];
if($status_code != 0){
    echo $error_type[$status_code];
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set a max execution time in your `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value max_execution_time 180
```

Answer (score 0):

To really *increase* the time limit i prefer to first get the current value. `set_time_limit` is not always increasing the time limit. If the current value (e.g. from `php.ini` or formerly set) is higher than the value used in current call of `set_time_limit`, it will *decrease* the time limit!

So what's with a small helper like this?

```
/**
 * @param int $seconds Time in seconds
 * @return bool
 */
function increase_time_limit(int $seconds): bool
{
    return set_time_limit(max(
        ini_get('max_execution_time'), $seconds
    ));
}

// somewhere else in your code
increase_time_limit(180);
```

See also: [Get max_execution_time in PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562398/get-max-execution-time-in-php-script)