# Get max_execution_time in PHP script

Tags: php

I know it is possible to set the maximum execution time in a script using either:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 30);
```

or

```
set_time_limit(30);
```

What can I do to get a variable containing the maximum execution time in seconds?

Comment: It should be noted that `ini_set('max_execution_time', 30);` and `set_time_limit(30);` are not completely synonymous, because `set_time_limit()` "resets" the counter to 0, which `ini_set()` does not.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The converse, using [`ini_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php):

```
ini_get('max_execution_time');
```

Note: if you check the documentation page for `ini_set`, you can find `ini_get` listed prominently on the "See Also" section. That's a very good way to discover functionality built into PHP that you are not already aware of.

Comment: Worth noting here (as detailed in other answers) that when you set the time with either `ini_set` or `set_time_limit()` then it resets the current time back to `0`

Answer (score 28):

There are some inaccurate points in the comments. So to clarify:

1. `set_time_limit(30)` is the same as `ini_set('max_execution_time', 30);`
2. Both of them reset the counter.
3. `ini_get('max_execution_time')` works for both cases - `set_time_limit` and `ini_set`.

Comment: set_time_limit increases the time in addition to max_execution_time. So being very specific, it's not the same (!==).

Comment: @ShivanandSharma I thought the same, but the other day I did a test with set_time_limit(1) and found that after a second the script ended due to the exceeded execution time. I'll have to do more tests, but I think it really resets the timers. At least the first call

Answer (score 25):

you can try

```
$max_time = ini_get("max_execution_time");
echo $max_time;
```

and you can use this variable the way you want to :)

Answer (score 13):

try this:

```
ini_get('max_execution_time')
```