# [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

Good day.

I have website on php5.

All query perform with sqlsrv;

When i make query i get error:

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]
```

How to fix error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This error is probably caused by a very slow connection or SQL query taking a long time.
- It is not an **SQL Server** problem.
- Try extending the timeout value in your connectionString in PHP.

  [**See this previous answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829403/how-to-increase-the-timeout-in-php)

> You need to change some setting in your php.ini : upload_max_filesize
>   = 2M  ;or whatever size you want
>
> max_execution_time = 60 ; also, higher if you must
>
> Were your PHP.ini is depends on your enviroment

Answer (score 0):

Setting `max_execution_time` to `0` (unlimited) alone, did not do it for me.

However, increasing the memory limit default from `128MB` to `2GB` worked:

```
max_execution_time = 0
memory_limit = 2048M
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3.19 to Sql Server 2008 all queries timed out including 'select getdate()'
Changing the two params max_execution_time to 0 and memory_limit = 1024M did it for me.