# PHPExcel reading large CSV is failing

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel

I am attempting to import a csv using PHPExcel into my application so that I can load the data into a table.  When the file reaches 2 meg+ the code fails.

I'm running Laravel on WAMP64.  The code that is failing is:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(Input::file('file')->getRealPath());
```

The error message is:

```
ErrorException: file_get_contents(C:\wamp\www\imax\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied in     C:\wamp\www\imax\vendor\phpoffice\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\OLERead.php:85
```

I know it's a size issue because the code completes properly when the file is 2048K.  I can add one character to the file pushing it to 2049K and it fails.  So it's not a permissions issue.

The line that fails in OLERead.php is:

```
// Get the file identifier
// Don't bother reading the whole file until we know it's a valid OLE file
$this->data = file_get_contents($sFileName, FALSE, NULL, 0, 8);
```

Wampserver 3.0.6

PHP 7.0.10

Comment: Have you tried uping the `memory_limit` in the php.ini file? There is also a timeout line and some other ones I would 'up' but i cant remember offhand. This may be help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829403/how-to-increase-the-execution-timeout-in-php

Comment: Memory limit was at 512M.  Doubled it after I discovered the error, no change.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to up the memory allocated for PHP. You can do that at runtime or change your php.ini config file.

**To up memory limit during runtime:**

`ini_set('memory_limit','16M');` Feel free to change the *16M* to what you need.

**To change it permanently:**

Open your *php.ini* file and look for this line `upload_max_filesize = 2M;` and change the 2M to what you desire.  *(i also believe WAMP lets you edit this by right clicking the icon and choosing on of the options)*

Note: You may want to just search for `upload_max_filesize` and leave out the = 2 M part as yours may be different.

Comment: Memory limit was already set to 512M before I got the error.  I increased it with no improvement before I logged the problem here.

Comment: Also changed the upload_max_filesize from 2M to 4M to 16M with no change to the resulting error.

Comment: @JEberlan could be time out or a different php option.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is using OLERead, then either you're not reading a large CSV file, but a BIFF-format xls file... or you're letting PHPExcel try and identify the filetype itself.... if you know that it is a CSV file, then instantiate the CSV Reader manually rather than letting PHPExcel try and identify the file.

```
// Tell PHPExcel that you want to load a CSV file
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
// Load the $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load(Input::file('file')->getRealPath());
```

However, if you know that you're working with CSV files, then it's more efficient to use PHP's native CSV reading function, [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: I changed to the PHPExcel_Reader_CSV but it ended in a similar error.  **ErrorException: fopen(C:\wamp\www\imax\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\imax\vendor\phpoffice\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Abstract.php:203**  So different piece of code, failing with the same misleading message.  I remove 1 character from the file and it works just fine.