# PHP MYSQL LOOP THROUGH A LARGE RESULT

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large mysql result set which I insert into other tables as I loop through.

```
//Code
$result= mysqli_query($daffff, "select * from 0_suppliers");
    while ($tran_pucha1we = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       //Several Inserts here
    }
```

The result set has around 3000 suppliers and inside the loop I insert into 4 other different tables which makes the process time out.

What ways are available to handle such large result sets without timing out?

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS in the title. It's considered yelling.

Comment: Hint: Pagination using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799193/mysql-data-best-way-to-implement-paging

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 2):

You should use INSERT query with SELECT statement which is much faster. Example:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2)
SELECT column1, 
column2 
FROM table2
```

where table2 is your table 0_suppliers.

Comment: assuming he is performing this for all suppliers, he will need to iterate through that table at some point.

Answer (score 2):

- Use transactions explicitly instead of relying on autocommit, to reduce overhead. You can do many statements in a transaction. But 12,000 is probably the upper limit of what I'd be confident in running in a single transaction.

  ```
  mysqli_begin_transaction($daffff);
  $result= mysqli_query($daffff, "select * from 0_suppliers");
  while ($tran_pucha1we = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     //Several Inserts here
  }
  mysqli_commit($daffff);
  ```
- Prepare the INSERT statements before the loop, and just execute them repeatedly within the loop.

  ```
  $result= mysqli_query($daffff, "select * from 0_suppliers");

  $insert1 = mysqli_prepare($daffff, "INSERT INTO MyTable1 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
  $insert2 = mysqli_prepare($daffff, "INSERT INTO MyTable2 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

  while ($tran_pucha1we = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert1, "sss", $tran_pucha1we[0], $tran_pucha1we[1], $tran_pucha1we[2]);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($insert1);

     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert2, "sss", $tran_pucha1we[3], $tran_pucha1we[4], $tran_pucha1we[5]);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($insert2);

  }
  ```
- Collect a bunch of rows of your SELECT query, and use multi-row insert syntax.

  ```
  INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
    (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), ...
  ```

You can combine all of the above techniques.

You may also like to know that you can change the PHP timeout. See this question: [How to increase the execution timeout in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829403/how-to-increase-the-execution-timeout-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

here is pagination using your code
it is timeout proof, but vulnerable as a result.  dont use this maybe, just get an idea.

```
$howMany = queryExec("select count(*) from 0_suppliers") -> fetch_array()[0];
$current = 0;
// this is how many records to process per loop, if it times out still, make it smaller.   
$numToProcess = 100;

// this is what you really came for...  but be careful:
set_time_limit();

while($current <= $howMany){
    $result= mysqli_query($daffff, "select * from 0_suppliers limit $numToProcess, $current");
    while ($tran_pucha1we = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       //Several Inserts here

       $current++;
    }
}
```

as many others have suggested, it is indeed a better idea to refactor and do a multi-line insert if possible, it is MUCH faster.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `limit` and `offset`

MySQL Limit & Offset documentation can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).

Examples can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp).