# nginx laravel keep getting 504 Gateway time out

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, laravel-5, connection-timeout

I keep getting 504 gateway time out error on nginx php7.0 ubuntu 16.04 for my laravel 5.3 website.

My suspicion `whereHas` query is the problem. When I commented out the query, it seems working fine.
the query

```
Item::with('image', 'brand', 'currency')->where('display', '>=', 3)->whereHas('catitems', function($query){
                $query->where('catitems.id', 5);
            })->inRandomOrder()->take(6)->get();
```

any idea whats wrong here?

my vultr vps spec is 1GB RAM, 1 Core.

This is the error log

> recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response
>   header from upstream

this is my buffer config

```
fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: If it is literally timing out, then you could try limit your `whereHas` query with `->take(5)` and see if that works. Otherwise, you can increase the PHP timeout with `max_execution_time = 60 ; also, higher if you must - sets the maximum time in seconds` (credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3829437/2053706))

Comment: The query does have take(6). I edited the question with the query. and my current max_execution_time = 5000, still timed out.