# How to upload video and audio in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want upload video in my Yii form

I try this:

```
$dbimage = '';
if (null != $patientmodel->treatment_videos) {
    $filename = uniqid() . '.' . $patientmodel->treatment_videos->extension;
    $patient_videos->saveAs($patientmodel->patientImgPath . '/' . $filename);
    $dbimage .= $filename . ',';
    $dbimage = rtrim($dbimage, ',');
    $patientmodel->treatment_videos = $dbimage;
}
```

output:I cannot select my video files

Comment: Did you read this? https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [UploadedFile class](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile) the easy sample code is:

**view.php**

```
<?= Html::beginForm('', 'post', ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) ?>
<?= Html::fileInput('attachment', '', ['id' => 'attachment']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit') ?>
<?= Html::endForm() ?>
```

**controller.php**

```
if ($file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('attachment')) { // check if file uploaded
   if (in_array($file->extension, ['mp3', 'wav'])) { // check valid audio file extensions
      $file_size_limit = 1024 * 1024 * 10 // 10mb
      if ($file->size < $file_size_limit) { // check max file size
         $path = 'path/to/directory';
         if ($file->saveAs($path)) { 
             return 'file uploaded successfully';
         }else{
             return $file->error;
         }
      }  
   }        
}
```

maybe you see this problems in your file uploadings:

- [increase upload_max_filesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)
- [increase max_execution_time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829403/how-to-increase-the-execution-timeout-in-php)

or for using in models you can use [input Uploading Files document](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload)