# How to to send huge data to server from cordova app

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, api, cordova

I'm using jquery serialize to send the form data from cordova app to PHP server, the form is a dynamic cart for user orders, it works with 30-35 items, but when user try to send more items, app fails.

We changed the post_max_size = 8M to 30M in php.ini but it fails too.

This is part of the form...

```
<li class="checkoutrow" style="position: relative;">
<input type="hidden" name="idproduct[]" value="'+cart[i].idproduct+'" id="idproduct" class="idproduct">
<input type="hidden" name="cod_prod[]" value="'+cart[i].cod_prod+'" id="cod_prod" class="cod_prod">
<input type="hidden" name="subtotal[]" value="'+subtotalneto+'" >
<input type="hidden" name="subtotaliva[]" value="'+subtotaliva+'" >
<h3 class="product-name">
<textarea name="description[]" style="width: 90%; color: #ae0000;" rows="2" readonly>'+cart[i].description+'</textarea>
</h3>
<span class="cart-delete"><a onclick="delete_cart_item('+i+', this);" href="#"><i class="fa fa fa-times"></i></a></span>
<div class="table">
<div class="qty col" style="width: 20%;"><input style="width: 98%; border: none;" type="number" name="qty[]" value="'+cart[i].qty+'" readonly ></div>
<div class="price col" style="width: 27%;"><input style="width: 98%; border: none;"  type="text" name="price[]" value="'+cart[i].price+'" readonly></div>
<div class="col" style="width: 23%;"><input type="text" style="width: 98%; border: none; text-align: center;" name="descuento[]" value="'+cart[i].descuento+'" readonly></div>
<div class="subtotalitem col" style="width: 30%;"><input style="width: 98%; border: none; text-align: right;" type="text" name="subtotalitem[]" value="'+subtotalitem+'" readonly></div>
</div></li>
```

Comment: Have you tried **max_execution_time**? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829403/how-to-increase-the-execution-timeout-in-php

Comment: No, I will try it, thanks for your advice

Comment: I don’t know of any limits of Cordova in sending data of any size - you can send images, video files much bigger than any shopping cart, so it seems (to me) that your upload gets stuck somewhere else.

Comment: I changed from 30 secs to 60(too much) and it fails too.

Comment: In the same app we send images with modern camera (big file) very fast. We send 30 - 35 items very fast but when user try to send 40 items app fails.

Comment: Have you used debugging to look at the size of the post? Is that really the issue? I suspect it is more likely a computational issue on the client or even more likely an issue doing the save server side.

Comment: Finally it works only when I send 30 to 40 items. I solved making a pagination of data. When detect last package I change the order status and give it as sent.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works only when I send 30 to 40 items. I solved making a pagination of data. When detect last package I change the order status and give it as sent.