# In a Cron Job what's the difference between GET and PHP and cURL

Tags: linux, cron

When setting up a cron job what is the difference as far as performance and script execution time between GET, cURL or PHP as the command to execute a PHP script (is a public page on the webserver).  The script can run for a long time (many minutes) and I don't want to get a script timeout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance difference for a multi-minute process between calling over HTTP vs calling via command line should be negligible.

If you hit the web page via http (like with curl), then you have 2 timeouts to deal with:

1. the http server timeout
2. php timeout [How to increase the execution timeout in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829403/how-to-increase-the-execution-timeout-in-php)

If you hit the php script via php command line only, then you only have one timeout to deal with.